# expose functionality equivalent in ng-cli 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am converting my application to use ng cli 6(full versioning below). Before I was just using webpack and in my old webpack configuration I took advantage of the expose-loader. I can't seem to find a ng cli 6 equivalent. I was wondering if anyone has dealt with this issue.

Specifically I used to have this line in my webpack configuration.

```
{ test: require.resolve('codemirror'), loader: 'expose-loader?CodeMirror' },
```

And I want to similarly expose CodeMirror at the global level.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but if you have to customize the loader or webpack configuration. With angular 6 it is temporarily disabled. So you cannot use ng eject to eject the webpack config and change it yourself. 

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10670

Comment: thank you @TaranjitKang. I saw that this was disabled so that I wouldnt have complete configurablity of the webpack. I was hoping there could be some way of doing this inside the ng cli tooling.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, if before you were not using the CLI. But as mentioned currently you cannot eject the webpack config in angular 6.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/upgrading-a-project-without-cli-to-angular-6-b07b105adc02